# recover them in json in vue js with bootstrap

Tags: html, json, vue.js

I configure this way what I get this way with the fat free framework
but when i want to recover in view js I see the elements but with unnecessary html characters

I try to set directly what I get in my html, I get the json but with bad characters

```
    $data = $Users->ReadUserData($_GET['action']);
    var_dump($f3->set("users", $data));
  }
```

```
    getDataUsers: function() {
      axios.get("http://localhost/?action=read")
      .then(function(response) {
        //console.log( "{{ @message }}" );
        if (response.data.error) {
          app.errorM = response.data.message;
        } else {
          //app.users = response.data.users;
          app.users = "{{ @users }}";
          console.log(app.users);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

result of app.users :

```
[{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;toto&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;toto@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0676565443&quot;},{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;jojo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;jojo@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0678654534&quot;},{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;jojo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;jojo@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0678654534&quot;}]
```

but at place of `"` i have `quot`

Comment: probably you need to use json_encode on the php output to prevent unwanted transformation,but can't your case.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @EmanueleParisio yes i use this in my model : "return json_encode($user);"

Comment: Try {!! !!} instead of {{  }}. By default laravel escapes all strings to prevent XSS, if you want to explicitly print special characters you have to mark the string to be safe, and you do that using {!! !!}, anything you print using that will not be escaped by laravel.

Comment: @Shuvojit I try this "app.users = "{{!! (at)users !!}}"; but i have syntax error, unexpected '!'

Comment: You are getting the syntax error on the php end or js end?

Comment: ok than it should be caused by vue {{ }} that trasform to raw text. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML
if using vuejs<2 you can try {{{ }}}

Comment: if i put "{{{ @users }}}" I have an internal message error that display : syntax error, unexpected '{', up :/